# Issues with macros in C

Tags: c, macros

I'm still trying to figure out macros in C:

```
#define A(x) #x

int main()
{
    int i = -i;
    char *s = A(i);

    i = -(s[0] == 'i');

    printf("%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Anyone care to enlighten me and comment the code, especially what the macro does and this line: `i = -(s[0] == 'i');`

Comment: What do *you* think it does?

Comment: Why not google for a tutorial? e.g. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html

Comment: It's not too broad. It's a simple, focused question with a code example.

Answer (score 7):

Read more about the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), notably [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)

So `A(i)`  is expanded into `"i"` literal string (and `A(strange !?)` would be expanded in `"strange !?"` , assuming that `strange` is not some `#define`-d preprocessor macro).  Hence `s[0]` is `'i'`, `(s[0] == 'i')` is true, represented as 1, so the output is -1 ...

You should have compiled your code with all warnings and debug information (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **run in a debugger** (`gdb`) your program step by step.

Notice also that `int i = -i;` is (as commented by [Cool Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049655/cool-guy)) [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior); you really should be afraid of UB since it can [be horrible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) (even if on my x86_64/Linux machine -with my usual compiler-, in this particular `int i= -i;` case, it probably won't do a lot of harm, just a tiny bit).

You can also watch the preprocessed form, obtained using `gcc -Wall -C -E`, in some editor or pager.

BTW your code sample is lacking `#include <stdio.h>`

PS. I recommend you to install Linux on your laptop and learn to use it (and its compiler) on the command line. Study also existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) code, you could find good examples of stringification with the C preprocessor.

Comment: Thank you this explains things. I'm using Codeblocks on Windows, so I'm restrained on how much I can do with the compiler.

Comment: Codeblocks is running a compiler command. So just find out what command it is running, and run that command yourself in a terminal. Then, tweak that command to give more warnings, and to show preprocessor output

Comment: @ranpos, then why don't you shift to linux. I used to work on Windows, for some months installed linux  on Virtual Box, and finally currently working on a Ubuntu laptop (Also, you can install two OS's on your computer).

Comment: The output when I compile it is -1. since the comparaisins [0] == 'i' is correct, so it outputs 1, plus the sign:  i = -(s[0] == 'i'); no?

Comment: @ranpos The comparision yields 1 and the unary minus operator makes it -1.

Comment: @ranpos BTW, what are you doing here: `int i = -i;`?? That invokes Undefined Behavior.

Comment: BTW, I also recommend using Linux to learn C or C++ programming (and  also to learn programming in general, using other languages, e.g. Scheme & [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)...)